# Mostrar Iframe dentro de un WebView

Tags: android

Necesito poder mostrar el contenido de un iframe en mi app que contiene un webview.

Resulta que tengo una app que contiene un webview, dentro de este se muestra un sitio de Internet (hasta ahí sin problemas), el problema surge que dentro de este sitio existe un botón que me lleva a una sección que es un iframe, pero lamentablemente al ingresar a esta sección el webview me muestra una imagen en blanco y no reproduce el contenido, he realizado varios cambios en mi código, como agregar permisos, etc.

Acá muestro el código de mi WebView.

```
private void valida_version() {
    final WebView webView;
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);


    webView.loadUrl("url");

    /*myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    myBrowser.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    myBrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myBrowser.loadUrl("http://m.cooperativa.cl");


    myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String msgToSend = "x";
           // Log.i("llego a onpage","si");
           myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:oldAppMsje.callFromActivity(\"" + msgToSend + "\")");
        }
    });*/
}
```

Acá muestro el código de mi Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeCoop"
    android:name="AnalyticsApplication"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

    <activity
        android:name="Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SinConexion"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Aca muestro lo que alcanzo a capturar de Log cat.

[image: Esto es lo que alcanzo a capturar del Log]

Es posible que me puedan ayudar orientándome un poco en lo que debo hacer?

Comment: algun error en la consola? (F12 en el navegador)

Comment: ese es el problema, la consola me manda muchas veces este error **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72

Comment: pero alcanzo a identificar algo como esto:

06-15 16:18:43.338 2615-2754/cl.android.app D/MediaResourceGetter: no ethernet/wifi connection detected
06-15 16:18:43.338 2615-2754/cl.android.app W/MediaResourceGetter: non-file URI can't be read due to unsuitable network conditions

Comment: Tiene pinta a problemas de permisos

Comment: mira el contenido de este link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955228/webview-with-an-iframe-android

Comment: @MiquelColl edité mi pregunta agregando el código que figura en la url que me indicas, pero aún así no he logrado que me funcione, te comento que dentro del sitio que se carga en el webview existe un boton para repoducir una streaming y dicho boton hace un llamado a un iframe.

Comment: Rodrigo 2 preguntas tienes aceleracion por hardware activada? el url a cargar es http://m.cooperativa.cl?

Comment: @Elenasys si, tengo activada la aceleracion por hardware en el manifest <application>, y la url que carga en el webview es la que me indicas, pero la url que se tiene que cargar al presionar el boton "radio en vivo" es otra "http://www.cooperativa.cl/radioenvivo/" y esta internamente carga un iframe que hace referencia a otro url

Comment: @Elenasys has podido encontrar alguna solución?, sería necesario que te comparta la url de github de mi proyecto?, yo he estado revisando la documentación de google, específicamente la documentación de webview y websettings, buscando entre todos los metodos que ahi existen si es que alguno me puede ayudar.

Saludos y muchas gracias

Comment: Si puedes compartirlo sería buena idea para que podamos probarlo. Me parece raro no funcione aun con android:hardwareAccelerated="true". En el browser imagino funciona sin problemas?

Comment: Exacto, cuando le quito el myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); y me abre las paginas en el navegador, esta me la abre sin problemas, dejo la url de mi github

https://github.com/RadioCooperativa/AndroidApp

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que saber que cuando se necesita incrustar código HTML como las etiquetas , se requieren dos requisitos en nuestra app.

El primero es tener activada la opción `android:hardwareAccelerated` y el permiso de acceso a Internet añadido en nuestro `Manifest.xml`, justo como esta en el ejemplo siguiente:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Otro de los posibles problemas, es no tener configurado el `WebChromeClient`, pero tu ya lo tienes configurado.

Además, te comento un pequeño detalle que acabo de ver en tu código repasando la respuesta.

Tienes que tener en cuenta que cuando cargar una web y cargar un contenido de una web, son cosas totalmente distintas aquí en Android.

Si quieres cargar una pagina web utiliza la función `loadUrl(url_pagina)`, pero si no, utiliza la función `loadData (String data, String mimeType, String encoding)`. Te muestro un ejemplo para entenderlo mejor y te dejo también la explicación de Google en [este](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) enlace:

```
    String frameVideo = "<html><body>Youtube video .. <br> <iframe width="320" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lY2H2ZP56K4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    WebView displayVideo = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    displayVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = displayVideo.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    displayVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Le pasas la `URL` del código que quieres mostrar como primer parámetro, en este caso el iframe, como segundo le pasas el tipo de dato `MIME` que sera y como tercero la codificación del dato.

Espero que sea alguna de esta soluciones y no haber entendido mal tu pregunta. Avísame si tienes algún problema o no es lo que necesitas.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Si muchas gracias por tu respuesta, si te fijas edite mi codigo que mostraba en la pregunta y está lo que me indicas en el manisfest, pero eso si en <application> agregue el  android:hardwareAccelerated="true" no en la activity como me lo indicas, influirá en algo?

Comment: Ya, justo cuando la publique lo he visto, pero voy a editar mi pregunta. Creo que ya se el fallo. De todas forma a lo que me preguntas de la activity, pruebalo, pero no tendría el porque influir en nada.

Comment: Detectaste el fallo?

Comment: Hola @Rodrigo acabo de editar la respuesta. Espero que te sirva y si no es ese el fallo avísame. ¡Suerte!

Comment: Estimado, creo que ese no es el problema que yo expongo, porque no tengo inconvenientes para reproducir videos de youtube por ejemplo, pero si un iframe especial de nuestro sitio que se debería mostrar al presionar un boton, desea que te envie la url de git de mi proyecto?

Comment: He puesto el ejemplo de un vídeo de Yotube por poner un ejemplo, pero ya que lo has mencionado, no estaría nada mal que en tu pregunta introdujeras la `URL` de `GitHub`. Así podría probar el código y entender mejor el fallo en cuestión. Gracias.

Comment: No muchas gracias a ti, este es la url GitHub

https://github.com/RadioCooperativa/AndroidApp

Comment: Pudiste revisar mi proyecto?, en realidad mi pregunta clave es, se entiende mi problema?

Comment: No he tenido tiempo aun para probarlo, realmemte estoy teniendo problemas con mi Android Studio. En cuando lo solucione, me pondre a ello y espero que no sea muy tarde.

Answer (score 1):

Te escribo otra respuesta porque no me cabía todo el texto que quería comentarte en un comentario. Te cuento.

Por fin he conseguido poder probar tu app en mi Android Studio y aunque no he conseguido saber el por qué de tu problema, puedo decirte algunas cosas que he averiguado.

He probado tu aplicación en un dispositivo con la versión de Android 6.0 (he tocado el `gradle` para que admita la versión) y cuando lo ejecute, como tu dices, no funcionaba, pero mientras repasaba el código con el emulador encendido, al rato, comencé a escuchar dicha radio. También tengo que decirte que pulse sobre el botón de `Radio en vivo` y luego pulsé sobre el `play`.

También decirte, que he buscado por Internet sobre el problema y he leído muchos comentarios diciendo que esta opción no funcionaba, que no era compatible con algunas versiones o incluso que podía ser por el tipo de formato de salida del audio el dispositivo. En todo caso, no he encontrado ninguna solución. Realmente no tienes fallos en tu código (o al menos que yo pueda identificar). Por lo que mis consejos son los siguientes:

1. Comprueba si la opción de la radio funciona ejecutándose directamente sobre el WebView en vez de sobre el `MediaPlayer`.
2. Comprueba si el streaming de la propia radio esta bien optimizado, puede que por no estarlo no se llegue a ejecutar o tarde demasiado.
3. Coge alguna app que este tipo y descomprimela para ver si puedes obtener alguna otra forma de realizar dicha función. Esta opción no se hasta que punto es legal, por lo que lo dejo en tus manos.

Como otros consejos útiles, te recomiendo que modifiques tu pregunta explicando que el problema es que **no consigues la reproducción de audio vía streaming en tu app** *y no que no te funciona un `iframe`, ya que son cosas distintas*. También introduce tu `URL` del `GitHub` en la pregunta para que puedan observar mejor tu código y ver algo que yo no he visto. Por ultimo, te recomiendo que también formules la pregunta en el `StackOverflow en ingles` y así tener doble posibilidad de encontrar la solución.

Para finalizar, *y esto es solo una opinión*, te recomiendo que no compatibilices con versiones tan bajas, a partir de la **API 17 o JellyBean** es más que suficiente y acoges a un grupo muy mayoritario de dispositivos (el **83%** si no me equivoco). Que bajes tanto la compatibilidad **puede darte muchos problemas**. Por otro lado, he visto que detectas que tipo de conexión se esta utilizando en el dispositivo y utilizas una función que será **obsoleta** en futuras versiones, por lo que te recomiendo que **no informes al usuario de si esta utilizando WiFi o datos, porque ese no es tu problema**, es el del usuario y cambies el comprobar la conexión por el siguiente código:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)                                          getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (info == null || !info.isConnected() || !info.isAvailable()) {
    return false; // Desconectado
} else {
    return true; // Conectado
}
```

También puedes ver otra forma de **detectar continuamente cómo comprobar la conexión**, por si da la casualidad de que una vez encendida la app, el usuario pierde la conexión.

- **[Mostrar una imagen jpg si se corta la conexión con el servidor en Android WebView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13537/4684)**

Siento no haber podido solucionar tu problema, pero al menos espero que te sirvan estos consejos.

Te deseo mucha suerte y si encuentras una solución, no dudes en contestarte a ti mismo para enriquecer aun mas la comunidad.

¡Suerte!

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias por el tiempo dedicado a formular esta respuesta, me parece muy completa tu explicación, quiero hacerte una consulta, cuando presionaste sobre el botón superior "radio en vivo" se te abrió una pantalla en blanco?, ese es el problema que tengo, además dicho botón no tiene relación alguna con el botón play inferior, voy a probar con lo que mencionaste en la url, es decir agregando la clase WebViewClientExternal, saludos y muchas gracias, te comento como me va y si encuentro solución.

Comment: Mencionaste además que ejecutaste la app en una versión 6.0 y tuviste que modificar el gradle quiere decir que no está soportando dicha versión?, además me mencionaste que cuando ejecutaste no funcionaba, precisamente que es lo que no te funcionaba? y qué ejecutaste para que comenzaras a escuchar la radio?, yo sólo tengo el boton play inferior validado para que se active la reproducción.

Comment: Hola como estás?, has podido encontrar alguna solución?, yo he estado mirando la documentación de google para probar métodos del webview  y websettings pero sin lograrlo :(

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, no he seguido probando tu aplicación, pero sí, cuando cliqué sobre `Radio en Vivo` me aparecía una pantalla en blanco y mucho tiempo después, sin hacer absolutamente nada, empezó a reproducir. Con lo de Android 6.0, no, no esta soportando la ultima versión y si no la soportaba me aparecía el mensaje de `No tiene conexión`, por lo que, como ya te dije, te recomiendo que modifiques esto para que soporte desde la API 17 hacia arriba. Te dije también que modificaras la pregunta para aclarar más lo que buscas. Realmente no te puedo ayudar mucho más, lo siento.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tus aportes y no te preocupes, cuando tenga la solución te la comentaré, eso si me parece extraño que comience a reproducir después de un tiempo no lo he podido comprobar, hice la modificación de la API y estoy corriendo la app en 6.0 sin problemas.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, ya lo he solucionado, lo que hice es que al final fue bien simple, al detectar ciertos sitios con la función WebViewClientExternal, me los abre en el browser (generalmente los iframe que no podía abrir), y los demás dentro de la app, Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Enhorabuena Rodrigo, me alegro que, por fin, hayas encontrado una solución. La verdad, me tenia un poco preocupada e intrega este problema, pero me alegro que lo tengas controlado. De todas formas, ¿no has conseguido reproducir la radio desde la app, no? Solo abriendola en un navegador externo. También te pido que escribas tu propia respuesta y la aceptes un día después, así los demás compañeros podran encontrar rapido la solución. Otra vez más, enhorabuena.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, y lamentablemente no he podido reproducir ningún iframe dentro de mi webview es por eso que tuve que abrir en el navegador todos aquellos elementos, y por supuesto dejare mi respuesta, saludos